# How to Monitor a fully managed Google cloud run with datadog APM?

Tags: google-cloud-run, datadog

I have an application container that I want to run on Google cloud run, for now It's running on a dedicated server and monitored using datadog, so I'm wondering how I can use datadog to monitor it after migrating it to cloud run?
I read in the DD docs that APM is not supported in the fully managed cloud run, so does that mean I can't move my app to cloud run?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Stay tuned, things are coming!

Answer (score 0):

If your application is written in Go, Python, Node.js or Java, it's now possible to do APM tracing with the Datadog agent. You can read more about it here:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/google_cloud_run/

*It's in BETA, so maybe there is some problems with it*